# Does Ophelia have her own avatar?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In the Framework, Daisy and Simmons (at least) had avatars whose places they took: people with their own personalities and backstories, quite different from their outside counterparts. At first it seemed that Ophelia was different, simply being the name that Aida used while in the Framework. However, after Daisy injures her, Aida exits the Framework.  *After* this, we see Ophelia talking to Fitz, urging him to complete Project Looking-Glass.

Does Aida have a presence inside the simulation even when not connected? Does Ophelia have her own avatar, and, if so, is she the same as Aida, or does she believe herself to be Madam Hydra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand she has the same kind of "avatar presence" than Daisy, Simmons or the other "real" people connected to the Framework, but **with the ability to connect/disconnect at will** (something that Daisy and Simmons would be able to do if they weren't blocked).

> Example: when Mace dies she disconnects herself to see him in the real world. If she was supposed to still be present in the Framework when disconnected, there would've been a dedicated scene to explain that.

Like Daisy and Simmons, she is definitely aware of being herself, not Madam Hydra. She is aware of the Framework and knows she is Aida the android, but don't show it for obvious reasons.

When she is disconnected, her framework body still exists but is "empty".

Inside the Framework, she also seems to have the same biological properties of a normal human being. Her body there is not the one of an android and she can be badly harmed, feel pain. Whether she will die or not if she is killed in the Framework is not known.

Comment: It would seem she doesn't "die" or her human body can take one hell of a lot of damage. I would think since she is basically writing the framework, she can do what she wants inside, although she can be "killed".